# Timer tick event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" OnTick="timer1_tick">                                        </asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lbltimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="tick" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

coding in page load in !IsPostback

```
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60).ToString();
```

This is the tick event coding. The problem is the tick event is not firing at all whenever I run the app. The app is Asp.net application.

```
protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
       DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
    {
        int hrs = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
        ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes)) / 60;

        int mins = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
        ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes)) % 60;

        int seconds = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
        ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds)) % 60;


        lbltimer.Text = "Time left is " + hrs.ToString() + " : " + mins.ToString() + " : " + seconds.ToString();

        if (mins == 1 && seconds == 0 && hrs == 0)
        {
            lbltimer.Text = "Please submit test 1min left";
        }
        else if (hrs == 0 && mins == 0 && seconds == 0)
        {
            lbltimer.Text = "Test Time Over";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you starting the timer?

Comment: in page load in not postback condition

Comment: You have posted code that will happen once the timer elapses. But for it to elapse it has to start first. Have you started the timer somewhere?

Comment: when im try to start the timer,start command wasn't coming in intelligence .

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Start' and no extension method 'Start' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) this is the error im getting

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404(v=vs.140).aspx
This is a walkthrough for timers.

Comment: I think you have to give the timer an interval for it to postback when it ticks.

Comment: yes i gave time interval as mentioned above     Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60).ToString();  and compare it with Datetime.now

Answer (score 0):

In this line of your code, add the timer interval. I do not see the interval being set any where.

```
<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" OnTick="timer1_tick" Interval="your_interval_in_ms">
```

Comment: you can also add the interval in the Code in a controlled manner. timer.Interval = value;

Comment: So is he waiting for 60 seconds?

Comment: interval is not an issue the tick event in not at all triggered